# Split zip file in Java (without .part)

Tags: java, zip

I have a zip file of 16 MB containing many log files, I want to split this zip in many other zip files of maximum size 6MB in my Java application.

I know it is possible with zip4j, but with Zip4j, my zip file is 'splited' to many parties (zip.part01 zip.part02) (I mean I cannot open any of these files without extracting them all).

Assuming that there is not any log file which size more than 6mb, what is the best approach to split my zip to many smaller zip files (and not parties) ? Unzipping the zip file, then looping on all the files and creating new smaller zips ?

I hope that my question is not confusing
Thank you very much

Comment: Yes "Unzipping the zip file, then looping on all the files and creating new smaller zips?" seems reasonable, but you can also iterate over entries of zip file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the file is a text file, I would just design the program to read certain portions of the file and create new files from those portions and zip them individually. By this way each file is readable.

This may not be as efficient as zipping the entire file and split it, though.